How to setup opportunity permission to restrict creating opportunity from a specific company?
Hallo Salesforce community,
I'm new in Salesforce and solving an issue from my colleague, which is all opportunity associated with the specific company should be checked and approved by my colleague, so that other colleagues cannot create the opportunity directly. Another requirement is that, the opportunity owner associated with the company should always be the specific user. Can these requirements be solved from non-code level?

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This community expects you to have tried to solve your own problem and to evidence this in your question. That might be just outlining your research, or it may be the configuration steps you tried but that did not work (explaining what the incorrect result was). What the community is not is a free consulting service.

I think your question is 'is it a standard feature ?'
the answer would be no.
There are all sorts of code in Salesforce - some that people don't call coding, like configuration or flows. But they are generally not accessible to users. You'll have to go to your Salesforce admin/developers to get this solved.
validation formula looks simplest - but ugly
or a Flow, nearly as ugly.
A post it not on his screen might or might not work :)
